# Regular expression to retrieve child tags of an xml irrespective of its position

Tags: xml, regex

What is the regular expression to retrieve one of the child tag's (ASObject) content of the  tag with grouping expression irrespective of the position of the child tag in the below xml. It may come as first one or the second one. But I wanted to retrieve the ASObject which has "postinjr" wage source code irrespective of its position. You can provide me the solution here...http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2usad

```
<insuredwages>
    <ASObject mappedClass="com.taliantsoftware.claims.wages.InsuredWagesDTO" encoding="0">
        <wagescategorytypecode tagClass="String">postinjr</wagescategorytypecode>
        <agreementid tagClass="double">2654630.0</agreementid>
        <jobtitle tagClass="String">Worker</jobtitle>
        <createddatetime tagClass="Date">2012-10-01 13:28:05.213 CDT</createddatetime>
        <new tagClass="boolean">false</new>
        <employmentstatustypename tagClass="String">Disabled</employmentstatustypename>
        <updated tagClass="boolean">false</updated>
        <voided tagClass="boolean">false</voided>
        <wagescategorytypename tagClass="String">Post Injury</wagescategorytypename>
        <employmentstatustypecode tagClass="String">dsabld</employmentstatustypecode>
        <useridcreated tagClass="double">111.0</useridcreated>
        <userupdated tagClass="String"/>
        <recordid tagClass="double">1030237.0</recordid>
        <usercreated tagClass="String">TESTER QA</usercreated>
    </ASObject>
    <ASObject mappedClass="com.taliantsoftware.claims.wages.InsuredWagesDTO" encoding="0">
        <agreementid tagClass="double">2654630.0</agreementid>
        <wagescategorytypecode tagClass="String">preinjr</wagescategorytypecode>
        <createddatetime tagClass="Date">2012-10-01 13:28:00.291 CDT</createddatetime>
        <new tagClass="boolean">false</new>
        <updateddatetime tagClass="Date">2012-10-01 13:28:00.291 CDT</updateddatetime>
        <updated tagClass="boolean">false</updated>
        <voided tagClass="boolean">false</voided>
        <wagescategorytypename tagClass="String">Pre-Injury</wagescategorytypename>
        <useridcreated tagClass="double">111.0</useridcreated>
        <userupdated tagClass="String">TESTER QA</userupdated>
        <useridupdated tagClass="double">111.0</useridupdated>
        <recordid tagClass="double">1036667.0</recordid>
        <usercreated tagClass="String">TESTER QA</usercreated>
    </ASObject>
</insuredwages>
```

Comment: Why don't you use something that is designed to navigate XML (i.e. not regex)?

Comment: no yaar, I cannot use any parser to navigate through the xml. I need this in a performance testing tool where I am creating load generation scripts in which it supports only regular expressions to retrieve contents from a response which is an xml data...

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Regular expressions are totally unsuited to this task. Use XPath, which is designed for the job.

For the explanation of why, see [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#) - a StackOverflow classic.

Comment: But the order of the tags is not at all predictable, so cannot use XPath. The insurewages tag is part of a big xml and not sure where it comes in.

Comment: >"But the order of the tags is not at all predictable, so cannot use XPath." You've clearly got some completely wrong ideas about XPath. It is designed precisely for this job.

Answer (score 0):

This would fetch the whole entry;

```
/<ASObject.*?>postinjr</wagescategorytypecode>.*?</ASObject>/gs
```

.. but it's strongly advised to use a XML-parser to properly process the data.

Here's a link to the RegExr: http://regexr.com?34cfg

This would fetch only it's inners (without `<ASObject> ... </ASObject>`);

```
/<ASObject.*?>(.*?>postinjr</wagescategorytypecode>.*?)</ASObject>/gs
```

.. and fetch group 1 (`$1`); http://regexr.com?34cfj

You should do another RegEx on the fetched content to separate the sub-items you've got. It will be very messy to make a situational RegEx to exactly get the data based on that inner value and also separate the items by group.

This is a very raw start to fetch the inner items, but it will only go down one level and will not handle escaped slashes and (`<`/`>`, `/`);

```
/<.*?>(.*?)</.*?>/gs
```

http://regexr.com?34cfm

If you really want to do everything in one RegEx, you should look into assertions;

- `?=`  Lookahead assertion
- `?!`  Negative lookahead
- `?<=` Lookbehind assertion
- `?!=` Negative lookbehind (or `?<!`)
- `?>`  Once-only Subexpression
- `?()` Conditon `[if then]`
- `?()|`Condition `[if then else]`
- `?#`  Comment

I'll leave, how all that works, to you to research ;)

Comment: Allendar, thanks for your reply, it has somehow helped me to get some idea on it. However I cannot retrieve matched content as a group as mentioned in the second url. I am getting whole xml without ASObject tags in it. Actually I am using this regular expression in NeoLoad tool in which the flags are not allowed :-( and the matched content can be retrieved with only group expression. If you have some idea on Neoload that might strike you.

Comment: The requirement is a bit more complex where I wanted to exclude some of the tags from the extracted content, like "updated", "employmentstatustypecode" tags for example.